# update label from background timer

Tags: ios, swift, background, uilabel

Good Day,

I am developing a workout app that works fine except when moving it to the background.  The timer suspends when it does.  I found an example of a background timer that I have working but now I can't get the UILabel that displays the duration of the workout to work.  In the console it states that I am accessing an object from the main thread which I understand.  What I don't know how to do is to get the UILabel to update as the timer updates from within the background thread with the update label being in the main thread.

Here is what I have (print statements help me follow the code):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var time = 0

    var timer = Timer()

    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var start: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var paused: UIButton!

    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        startButtonPressed()

    }

    @IBAction func pausedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        pausedButtonPressed()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    func updateTimerLabel() {

        let hours = Int(self.time) / 3600
        let minutes = Int(self.time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(self.time) % 60

        timerLabel.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)

    }

    func startButtonPressed() {

        outputLabel.text = "Workout Started"
        start.isHidden = true
        paused.isHidden = false

        _backgroundTimer(repeated: true)
        print("Calling _backgroundTimer(_:)")

    }

    func pausedButtonPressed(){

        outputLabel.text = "Workout Paused"
        timer.invalidate()
        pauseWorkout()

    }

    func pauseWorkout(){

        paused.isHidden = true
        start.isHidden = false

    }


    func _backgroundTimer(repeated: Bool) -> Void {
        NSLog("_backgroundTimer invoked.");

        //The thread I used is a background thread, dispatch_async will set up a background thread to execute the code in the block.

        DispatchQueue.global(qos:.userInitiated).async{
            NSLog("NSTimer will be scheduled...");

            //Define a NSTimer
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self._backgroundTimerAction(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
            print("Starting timer")

            //Get the current RunLoop
            let runLoop:RunLoop = RunLoop.current;

            //Add the timer to the RunLoop
            runLoop.add(self.timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode);

            //Invoke the run method of RunLoop manually
            NSLog("NSTimer scheduled...");
            runLoop.run();

        }

    }

    @objc func _backgroundTimerAction(_ timer: Foundation.Timer) -> Void {

        print("_backgroundTimerAction(_:)")

        time += 1

        NSLog("time count -> \(time)");
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("viewDidLoad()")

        print("Hiding buttons")
        paused.isHidden = true
        start.isHidden = false

        print("Clearing Labels")
        outputLabel.text = ""
        timerLabel.text = ""

        print("\(timer)")
        timer.invalidate()
        time = 0

    }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the view controller and I want to update the Duration.

[image: snapshot]

Any assistance anyone can provide is greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,

Kevin

Comment: I don't understand, if your app is in the background, there's no UILabel to update since it's not shown. You should just keep track of the value of your timer in a propery and when `viewDidAppear` is fired (UILabel is back on the screen) , update your UILabel using the current value of the timer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of trying to run a timer in the background, record the `startDate` of the start of your workout and compute the time interval.  That way, the app doesn't actually have to run in the background to keep track of the workout time.  The timer will only be used to update the user interface.

Pausing now works by recording the current workout interval.  When the workout restarts, it subtracts the current workout interval from the `Date()` to get a new adjusted `startDate`.

Add notifications for the app entering the background and foreground so that you can restart the UI update timer if the workout is active:

```
import UIKit

enum WorkoutState {
    case inactive
    case active
    case paused
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var workoutState = WorkoutState.inactive
    var workoutInterval = 0.0
    var startDate = Date()

    var timer = Timer()

    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var start: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var paused: UIButton!

    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        startButtonPressed()

    }

    @IBAction func pausedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        pausedButtonPressed()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    func updateTimerLabel() {
        let interval = -Int(startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)
        let hours = interval / 3600
        let minutes = interval / 60 % 60
        let seconds = interval % 60

        timerLabel.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)

    }

    func startButtonPressed() {

        if workoutState == .inactive {
            startDate = Date()
        } else if workoutState == .paused {
            startDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-workoutInterval)
        }
        workoutState = .active

        outputLabel.text = "Workout Started"
        start.isHidden = true
        paused.isHidden = false

        updateTimerLabel()
        _foregroundTimer(repeated: true)
        print("Calling _foregroundTimer(_:)")

    }

    func pausedButtonPressed(){

        // record workout duration
        workoutInterval = floor(-startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)

        outputLabel.text = "Workout Paused"
        workoutState = .paused
        timer.invalidate()
        pauseWorkout()

    }

    func pauseWorkout(){

        paused.isHidden = true
        start.isHidden = false

    }

    func _foregroundTimer(repeated: Bool) -> Void {
        NSLog("_foregroundTimer invoked.");

        //Define a Timer
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerAction(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
        print("Starting timer")

    }

    @objc func timerAction(_ timer: Timer) {

        print("timerAction(_:)")

        self.updateTimerLabel()
    }

    @objc func observerMethod(notification: NSNotification) {

        if notification.name == .UIApplicationDidEnterBackground {
            print("app entering background")

            // stop UI update
            timer.invalidate()
        } else if notification.name == .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive {
            print("app entering foreground")

            if workoutState == .active {
                updateTimerLabel()
                _foregroundTimer(repeated: true)
            }
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(observerMethod), name: .UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(observerMethod), name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

        print("viewDidLoad()")

        print("Hiding buttons")
        paused.isHidden = true
        start.isHidden = false

        print("Clearing Labels")
        outputLabel.text = ""
        timerLabel.text = ""

        print("\(timer)")
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

Just call `updateTimerLabel()` on the main loop:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.updateTimerLabel()
}
```

Full function:

```
@objc func _backgroundTimerAction(_ timer: Timer) {

    print("_backgroundTimerAction(_:)")

    time += 1

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.updateTimerLabel()
    }

    NSLog("time count -> \(time)")
}
```

---

Notes:

1. Running the timer on a background thread isn't buying you anything but trouble in setting it up.  I'd recommend just running it on the main thread.
2. There is no need to add `-> Void` to a Swift function definition; that is the default.
3. Swift typically doesn't need the semicolons `;`, so lose those.
4. `self.time` is already an `Int`, so creating a new `Int` from it is unnecessary.

   replace:

   ```
   let hours = Int(self.time) / 3600
   ```

   with:

   ```
   let hours = self.time / 3600
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I made the changes and it works in the simulator but when running it on my iPhone it doesn’t,t continent running the timer in the console as it did with the simulator.

Comment: You mentioned that I don’t need to run the timer in the background but if the user is running the workout app and sends it to the background the timer stops an therefor the calculation for active energy burned is wrong because it needs an accurate duration for the workout.  The user can also monitor the workout time when the app is brought bac to the forground.  I can’t see any other way to get the results I am looking for except to have the timer run in the background, allow the user to pause and restart and bring up music app sending this app to the background.

Comment: .  Any suggestions on how to get the same results I get from the simulator with the device?

Comment: Another way to implement a timer is to just record the start time.  Then when it is time to update the UI, you calculate the time elapsed between the start time and the current time.  That way, it doesn't need to run while the app is in the background.

Comment: @kdcattran, I updated my answer to address your needs for the timer to keep track of workout time even when it is in the background.

Comment: I did run into an issue and through researching the issue have discovered what I believe it is.  I implemented the background timer with my main workout app and it does not reset the interval constant upon completing one exercise and moving on to another.  If I force quit it works fine but I need to be able to stop and save one exercise then be able to start another while in the app.  I made the interval constant to a var at the beginning of the code to be able to track the interval for other functions and reset it to 0 in the view did load which I call upon completing one exercise.

Comment: However, in the updateTimerLabel( ) it reassigns the the value from:  interval = -Int(timerStartDate.timeIntervalSinceNow) back to the previous value.  I'm not sure how and where to reset this value to get the results I'm looking for.  As always, your assistance is tremendously appre

Comment: Describe the UI to me. When the user is done with a workout, do they hit a stop button? Is that when you save the info? Then, what do they do to start the next workout.

Comment: When you stop the exercise, set the workout state to `.inactive`, invalidate the timer and compute the final interval then. Then, the next time you hit start it will create a new startDate and start back at zero.

Comment: Also, you should never call viewDidLoad yourself. If you need to redo the setup code you put in viewDidLoad, move that code to a separate function in you ViewController and call it from viewDidLoad and from the code that needs to reset the workout.

Comment: Here's the flow of the UI.  The user selects an exercise from a picker and data is displayed.  They then press the Start button that only appears after a valid picker selection.  Once Start is pressed, it starts the elapsed time of the workout while making recurring calculations on the screen.  Start is replaced with the Pause button.  If Pause is pressed, an alert is presented to see if the user want to pause the workout or exit.  If pause is selected, the Start button appears and a state of the workout is displayed "Workout Paused".  If pause is not selected, the user gets another alert.

Comment: This alert prompts the user if they wish to save or discard the workout.  If they discard, nothing happens and everything should reset to the original state at app startup.  If they do save, it saves the workout to HealthKit and resets everything to the original state.

Comment: OK.  So, invalidate the timer when they press Pause, set the workoutState to `.paused` if they're just pausing, and set it to `.inactive` when they have stopped the workout.  The next time they press Start, the `.inactive` state will cause the timer to start from zero.  You can set the workout state to `.inactive` in your function that sets everything to the original state.

Comment: So, the user can press the Start button to exit a paused state and to begin a new workout.  I may have to reconsider my user interaction to accommodate this action? My response is behind yours. So, I'll try the recommended solution.  Thank you!

Comment: Correct.  It depends on the workoutState what the Start button does.  I already wrote it to handle both cases.  The workoutState tells the start button to either continue (if workoutState is .paused) or start from zero if workoutState is .inactive.

Comment: Not related to the question but you can make `print("timerAction(_:)")` generic changing it to `print(#function)`