# Timer app: Date subtraction vs NSIntervalTimer

Tags: ios, swift, date, timer

I am making an app that has a timer function; the smallest time period it times is seconds, so I don't really think I need to use date subtraction, as  an Timer.scheduledTimer doesn't lose accuracy until it starts getting to intervals of about 0.1-0.2.

My question is: Should Timer.scheduledTimer be alright for this timer app, and are there any particular advantages/disadvantages of using either method (note I am showing multiple timers at once)?

*Note: the reason I am asking this is because I have seen some people talk about date subtraction, but I think this is only needed for timing very accurately.*

Comment: What is `NSIntervalTimer`? Do you mean `(NS)TimeInterval`?

Comment: I mean Timer.scheduledTimer

Comment: If you want your timers to continue while your app is in the background, you should use date subtraction.  Only use Timer.scheduledTimer to update your display.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50200606/1630618

Comment: Definitely use date subtraction.