# Updating a timer in ios when app goes in and out of background

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swift4, ios11

I have an app that has a timer in a view controller that counts down from 5 minutes to 0:00.

It stops when the app goes into the background per ios/Apple rules of app suspension.

How do I grab the time before it goes to sleep and update it in seconds when it comes back? I know you can't use background processing for long so avoiding that.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50200606/1630618

Comment: Try saving value in user defaults inside applicationwillenterbackground. And retrieve value in maybe didfinishlaunching (appdelegate.swift)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a good use case for UserDefaults.
This can be done in your main view controller.

ViewController.swift

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

var timer = Timer()
var timerCount = 300

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let timeLeft = defaults.integer(forKey: "timerLeft1")
    if timeLeft != 0 {
        timerCount = timeLeft
    }

    startTimer()
}

func startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateCounter() {
    if timerCount > 0 {
        timerCount -= 1
        defaults.set(timerCount, forKey: "timerLeft1")
    } else {
        timerCount = 300
    }
}
```

Apple docs: [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: **Do not** call `.synchronize()`. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize)… _"this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_