# timer pause button reseting when press start again

Tags: swift4, nstimer, xcode9

So I have a program which is a stopwatch and I have the stopwatch is working but when I press the pause button the thing pauses but when I press the start button again to start the stopwatch from where it left off it resets instead I have tried multiple thing but nothing seems to work can you help me. 
below is my code that I have for my reset, start and pause function they are all IBactions and Outlets.

I think the problem is with the start or pause buttons

```
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if(isPlaying) {
        return
    }
    startButton.isEnabled = false
    pauseButton.isEnabled = true
    isPlaying = true

    let aSelector : Selector = #selector(ViewController.updateTime)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    counter = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

}


@IBAction func pauseTimer(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    startButton.isEnabled = true
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false


    timer.invalidate()
    isPlaying = false

}

@IBAction func resetTimer(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    startButton.isEnabled = true
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false

    timer.invalidate()
    isPlaying = false
    counter = 0.0
    timeLabel.text = String("00:00:00:00")

}
```

then I also have my Updatetimer part which I'm sure works fine but f you need it just ask!!

If you need more info or specifications just ask or leave a comment.

here is my update timer

@objc func updateTime() {
        let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

```
    //Find the difference between current time and start time.
    var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - counter

    //calculates the hour in elapsed time
    let hours = UInt8(elapsedTime / 3600.0)
    elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(hours) * 3600.0)
    //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
    elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.
    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)

    //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.
    let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

    //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants
    let strHours = String(format: "%02d", hours)
    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

    //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel
    timeLabel.text = "\(strHours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds):\(strFraction)"
}
```

Comment: I think you need to keep track of the timer state with an enum perhaps.  When the start button is pressed, if the timer has been paused you don't change the `counter`.

Comment: I would only use the timer to update the display.  Use time diffs to calculate the time remaining.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50200606/1630618) for an example of a timer with a pause.

Comment: I tried that and it gave me the error "Use of unresolved identifier..."

Comment: *I tried that*.  What exactly did you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line `counter = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` in your `startTimer()` function. You should only set the counter if the `counter == 0.0`. So change your code such as following:

```
     if counter == 0.0{
          counter = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        }else{
          counter = previousDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        }
```

also add the following line to your pause function, so it saves the date that counter was paused, so the next time the counter will start from that point:

```
var previousDate = NSDate()
@IBAction func pauseTimer(_ sender: AnyObject){
//...Your other code...
previousDate = NSDate()
}
```

Also your `update` function should use the saved date `previousDate` for updating the counter.
That should fix the problem.

Comment: this does not actually work it just sets the view to zero but the counter is still going so when you press start it just displays the current time without it being paused

Comment: im not sure hoe to save the date using the previousDate so I attached my updatetime function can you please help me or edit my function to save the previousdate.